# jQuery SerialScroll Cycle Parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollto, serialscroll

Everyone --  I'm currently using SerialScroll (and ScrollTo) to power a next and previous function on my site.  Is there a setting within SerialScroll that would allow the cycle parameter to continue moving to the right when it reaches the end of the series instead of scrolling left all the way back to the beginning?  If I have four sections (e.g. a,b,c,d), it would go from a --> b --> c --> d --> a --> b --> etc. without scrolling back thru c and b when it loops around to a.

Conversely, I'm looking for the same bit of functionality when a user uses the previous button.  For example d --> c --> b --> a --> d --> c --> etc. without scrolling back thru b and c when it loops around to d.

I'm not using the AutoScroll option, and instead requiring my users to click on a next or previous button.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand very well but I think they want a repeat cycle but continuously.

This may I can help.

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/carousel.php

Comment: I'm looking for an option to allow for "infinite" scrolling using the ScrollTo jQuery plugin.  I have not tested out the Carousel plugin yet, but may decide to give it a go if I can't get the functionality I need.